# read csv function sparklyr error

Tags: r, sparklyr

I'm trying to read a csv file into strudio with sparklyr package in a google compute cluster. This is the configuration:

Test Spark framework

```
install.packages("sparklyr")
install.packages("dplyr")


library(sparklyr)
spark_install(version = "1.6.2")


 Sys.setenv(SPARK_HOME="/usr/lib/spark")
 config <- spark_config()

  sc <- spark_connect(master = "yarn-client", config=config ,version = "1.6.2")
```

There is an error indicating "Invalid argument" just after pasting the path string that I will use for the spark_read_csv function. And it keeps popping up even if I do not click the save button.

Any idea why I'm getting this error? Interestingly I just tried same install configuration in amazon EMR and had the same issue.

Albit[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to use quotes around the `name` argument in `spark_read_csv`. Have you tried that? See `?spark_read_csv`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion schristel, but I I used the format indicated in the spack_read_csv guide and I still experience errors. In the case of google compute I transfered the file to the rstudio workspace and tried with "file://home/ruser/filename" and "file:///home/ruser/filename".

Comment: Okay, I can't help troubleshoot without a reproducible example, but best of luck. Follow up if you find the solution!

Comment: Thank you Schristel. This is how I have setup the command: secondary_two_tbl <- spark_read_csv(sc, "SECONDARYtwo.csv", 
                          path =  "file:///home/ruser/sparkly-blog")

Comment: And this is the error: Error: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 3 in stage 19.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 3.3 in stage 19.0 (TID 3057, cluster-2-w-1.c.hadhoop-163507.internal): java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/home/ruser/sparkly-blog/packrat/src/BH does not exist

Comment: The "SECONDARYtwo.csv" is located in the folder: /home/ruser/sparkly-blog/

Comment: I can't access a file that you're reading in locally. But from the error `FileNotFoundException` - it looks like you aren't providing the correct path. I would try changing the path name - check the root where you're storing the file and make sure they match.

Comment: > getwd()
[1] "/home/ruser/sparkly-blog"                        > list.files()
[1] "data"             "functions"        "LICENSE"          "main.R"           "packrat"         
[6] "SECONDARYtwo.csv" "settings"         "spark-blog.Rproj" "visuals"         
>

Comment: Schristel -- Those are the getwd() and list.files() command results. The file "SECONDARYtwo.csv" is in the "/home/ruser/sparkly-blog" working directory. Am I missing something. Maybe I am, I'm very new to spark..

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the previous error by creating a directory at hadoop, transferring the file to hadoop /user/ directory and then using the spark_read_csv function:

```
  secondary_two_tbl <- spark_read_csv(sc, "SECONDARYtwo.csv", 
                      path =  "/user/ruser/secondary/")
```

Then I got a new error:

```
Error: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: It is not allowed to add database prefix `SECONDARYtwo` for the TEMPORARY view name.;
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.CreateViewCommand.<init>(views.scala:79)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$createOrReplaceTempView$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2421)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$createOrReplaceTempView$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2415)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$withPlan(Dataset.scala:2603)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.createOrReplaceTempView(Dataset.scala:2415)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.registerTempTable(Dataset.scala:2385)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at sparklyr.Handler.handleMethodCall(handler.scala:118)
at spar
```

After this I tried removing the ".csv" part from the "SECONDARYtwo.csv" file and run the spark_read_csv function again..

```
   tbl_secondary_two <- spark_read_csv(sc, "SECONDARYtwo", 
                      path =  "/user/ruser/secondary/")
```

This last time it worked.